# output vector with user defined function

Tags: c++, stl, foreach

In below code snippet , can anyone let me know how to print the functor value output (3,4,5,6,7) without
embedding add function in class.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

void add ( int i)
{
i=i+2;

}

int main()
{
vector <int> vec ={1,2,3,4,5};

for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(),add);


for (auto i:vec)
{

cout<<i;
}


return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the function to take a reference:

```
void add ( int& i)
{
  i+=2;
}
```

This will modify the original vector. If this is not desired, then make a copy:

```
vector <int> vec ={1,2,3,4,5};
vector<int> vec2(vec);
for_each(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), add);
for (auto i : vec2)
  cout<<i;
```

Comment: copying doesn't work even without reference. so reference seems to be only solution in this case.

Comment: @user2997518 Of course, you always need the reference. Otherwise the function has no effect at all.

Answer (score 1):

`for_each` does not modify the elements passed to it or pass them by reference.

```
// Example implementation
template<class InputIterator, class Function>
  Function for_each(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Function fn)
{
  while (first!=last) {
    fn (*first);
    ++first;
  }
  return fn;
}
```

If you have c++11 you can use a lambda:

```
for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(),[&] (int& i) {
    i += 2;
});
```

Otherwise, you can use `std::transform`, with the source vector used as the destination.

```
std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(), [] (int i) { 
    return i + 2; 
});
```

Comment: It seems to be good approach, even without  reference  lambda and transform works .

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use `std::transform()`? No need for the `add()` function. Since the posted `add()` function has no side effect, it can't be used anyway.

```
std::vector<int> vec = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(),
               [](int value) { return value + 2; });
```